# how to pass variables from a views style-template to the row-template it invokes

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a custom style-plugin for views, and a corresponding style-template (*my-style-template.tpl.php*).
Similarly, I created a custom row-plugin for views and a corresponding row-template.

The style-template loops through the views-rows, and invokes the row-template on each row:

`print $row;`

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

The style-plugin defines certain settings in the $options variable, which gets passed to the style-template.  The row-template needs access to some of these settings.

**My question:**

Is there a way to pass variables from my style-template to my row-template?
For example, rather than invoking `print $row` from the style-template, is there some other way of invoking the row-template, which allows me to pass variables to the row-template?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass variables from one template file to another.  That is not how things work.

However, a general rule is that every template file has a corresponding preprocess function for creating the variables available in the template.

So, you need to figure out what preprocess functions are being called.  The [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module can help out with this.  The [theme.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/7) file lists all of the preprocess functions that the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module uses.

With those, the standard way of handling things is something like

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
}
```

Once you have the `$view` object, you have everything you need.  However, you often need to [`dpm($view)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) to figure out what is there and/or look at the default preprocess functions.

Comment: Thank you!  When I dpm($view), I see that the style-options are available to the row-template in $view->style_options